# Meaning of _ for setting the value of a variable

Tags: scala

I am exploring scala with a background from java. I am trying to understand usage of _ when it has been used to set the value of an attribute.

This is my code snippet.

```
class RectAngle{
     var length=1
     var height=20
   }

object RectAngleDemo extends App{
  var f = new RectAngle()
  f.length=20;
  f.length_=(10)
  println(f.length);
  f.height=20;

}
```

From the code, I know that value of length is 10 but don't know how it is allowed and how it worked here.

I have gone through other question (for which this question has been marked as duplicate) and still did not understand the concept with respect to my current query.

I am interested only in this example because digesting other question is very difficult at this juncture due to lot of theory in it without examples.

***In above example, how does _ work?***

Comment: You're doing it wrong man. The fun in Scala comes in never using a Java-style `var` ever again. Otherwise, just code in Java, it's a hell of a lot easier for this kind of thing.

Comment: FTR, Scala vars also beat Java.

Comment: There are use cases for `var`s in Scala for sure. Think Actors, etc.